# Some problems with primefaces pdf viewer

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces, viewer

Two questions:

1º This piece of code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE, where I only can see a grey box displayed in the dialog panel (IE 11 windows 7)

```
<p:dialog ...>
<p:media value="/tmp/doc.pdf" width="800px" height="400px" player="pdf">  

</p:media> 
</p:dialog>
```

2º Also, I'd like users only to view the file, not to download, print, ... So I'd like to hide the toolbar of the pdf viewer. I've tried playing with parameters [pdf parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) but the example below doesn't work

```
<p:media value="/tmp/doc.pdf#toolbar=0 ..."
```

If I use `<Object>` instead `<p:media>` I don't get the toolbar working (and I don't know why), but it still doesn't work on IE.

Curiously, if I go to [primefaces media demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml) page with IE, I can see the pdf viewer demo without problems, and I suppose that this page is written with primefaces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `<p:overlayPanel>` instead of `<p:dialog>` now it works fine on IE (and Chrome, Firefox ...).
Also, the "#toolbar=0" parameter works fine... but only in IE.

I realize that the viewer of IE is the acrobat reader (acroPDF.dll) and it works fine when I use

```
<p:overlayPanel ...>
    <object data='tmp/doc.pdf#toolbar=0' type='application/pdf'  height=...'/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Chrome and Firefox use another viewers.
Does anyone know how I can indicate this viewers not to show the toolbar?

Thanks again